# Update all wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

I need make all of my posts update. I use bulk upload for store, but in web page posts/products dont show, when i hit update, posts/products are showed up.

I think use wordpress default update function:

```
// Update post 37
  $my_post = array();
  $my_post['ID'] = 37;
  $my_post['post_content'] = 'This is the updated content.';

  // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

But how to get in arrays all posts id?

Comment: i have the same issue as you describe. I don't understand what the different between doing a foreach and wp_update_post and clicking the update button is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go, you just loop through the posts with a foreach.

```
/*
Plugin Name: Example
Description: This is not just a plugin, it's <em>CODE</em>..
Author: 
*/
add_action('init','example_hide');

function example_hide(){

    $my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => 10 ) );

    foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):

    $my_post['post_content'] = 'This is the updated content.';

    wp_update_post( $my_post );

    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me, but I will try it on the init hook as you show as at the moment, I'm doing it in a admin menu page callback.

Comment: I used this to resave all my CPTs (which was needed to build a map based on data in a custom table) - I used this and it worked perfectly, however, I removed the $my_post['post_content'] so no post information would be updated. This worked for me. Make sure you refresh a page to make it run.

Comment: Thanks rockmandew, as a note, I usually throw this kind of code in a plugin. That's what the header is for. Activate, wait, deactivate, and you are done~! This method keeps 'one time' code out of the templates or theme.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [WordPress' `get_posts` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Try:

```
$all_posts = get_posts('numberposts=');
```