# Update all posts - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917725/update-all-wordpress-posts) thread and tried to implement the given code sample there;

```
//code snippet to mass update all posts
add_action('init','mass_update_posts');

function mass_update_posts(){

    $all_posts = get_posts('numberposts=');

    $my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => $all_posts ) );

    foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

    endforeach;  
}
```

I put the code in my footer.php but it doesn't seem to do anything? What am I missing? Initially I used;

```
$my_posts = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => -1 ) );
```

But that didn't help either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand what you are trying to do with this code...

First every time someone loads the page the footer.php will fire so you want to mass update all of your posts with a loop of the post itself?

There about a million things wrong with what you are trying to do with this code.

1. Never add actions in a footer file they belong in the function.php file of a theme.
2. Your $all_posts variable is probably empty because you are sending a function expecting an array of arguments a string ([please read the get_post() function documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts))
3. $all_posts is not an integer as you are using it the next line (the get_post() function returns a list of WP_Post objects.
4. Your loop goes through all your posts and updates them with the same post, changing nothing and effectively accomplishing nothing.

So I guess the real question is what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited data manually in the mysql database which only shows on each page if I 'edit' the page and press 'update'. Hence the empty update. I realise that putting it in the footer is daft, but it was simply so I could run the code quickly once, update the posts, then remove it. I agree I shouldn't be so lazy and make something to fire it safely, but I'm still a WP newbie..